# Module type definition relying on global one

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have installed reacttype definitions with the following command

```
typings install npm~react --save
```

So I have it in the folder

```
typings/modules/react
```

For react-dom there is only the global module available, that can be installed with the command

```
typings install dt~react-dom --save --global
```

And it goes in folder

```
typings/globals
```

Now React-Dom is unable to find react definitions because it expect to find it in the global folder.
What is the supposed way to deal with this scenario?

I honestly don't know the difference between global and module definitions... And the Typings readme is not explaining it.
I am starting using the npm definitions because they are more up to date.